# Iterate over ifstream

Tags: c++

I know there are a lot of answers already on how to iterate ifstreams but non of them really helped me finding a solution.

My problem is:
I have a txt file containing multiple lines of data. The first line of the txt file tells me how the rest of the data is composed.
for example this is my txt file:

```
5 5 5
0.5 0.5 0.5
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 -1
0.5 1 0
0 0 -1 0
0 0 1 1
0 -1 0 1
1 0 0 3
0 1 0 1
...
```

so this should tell my program to do

```
double a,b,c
inf >> a >> b >> c
```

for the first 5 lines

```
double a,b,c,d
inf >> a >> b >> c >> d
```

for the next 5 lines
etc

i guess i might be able to do this by using `getLine()` and then splitting the resulting String on every " " but i was wondering if there is any 'cleaner' way of doing this.

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Are you having a problem? If so, what is it?

Comment: Getting the lines using [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is a good start. Then you can put them in an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and use the normal input operator `>>` to get each lines numbers.

Comment: You're doing formatted *line* input. Reading each line and processings it's formatted layout is, by that very definition, a proper way to do it.

Comment: @Joachim, thanks for the reply, didn't know about istringstream. Accepted mostruash's answer since it did what I needed with less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    double a,b,c;
    inf >> a >> b >> c;
    // Do something with a,b,c
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    double a,b,c,d;
    inf >> a >> b >> c >> d;
    // Do something with a,b,c,d
}
```

Comment: when does `inf >> ` go to the next line? after each 'word' in the line is used?

Comment: It will go to the next line when searching for a double don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

yes use getline in a while loop and parse data using istringstream and istream_iterator and keep individual data in vector.

```
int main()
{

 std::ifstream infile(<absolute path to file>);
 std::string input="0 0 -1 0";
 std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
 while( getline(infile,input))
 {
    std::istringstream iss(input);
    std::vector<float> input_data{istream_iterator<float>{iss},
                      istream_iterator<float>{}};
    data.push_back(input_data);   
}

for( const auto & x: input_data)
  std::cout<<x<<" ";
}
```